# Reusing Django apps in own project which require a lower Django version

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, virtualenv

I am relatively new to Django and Python so I guess I am missing some basics here.

I want to use [django-editlive](http://editlive.motion-m.ca/) and therefore also [dajaxice](http://www.dajaxproject.com) in my Django 1.6 project/app.

First I installed dajaxice and got it to work (although I ran into a similar situation as described below...). Then I cloned django-editlive from github, installed it on my OS X 10.9 with `sudo python setup.py install`. I noticed in the shell output that a new django egg was placed: `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.5-py2.7.egg/`. After  I added editlive to my settings.py I get an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.5-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.5-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.5-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 252, in fetch_command
app_name = get_commands()[subcommand]
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.5-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 101, in get_commands
apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.5-py2.7.egg/django/utils/functional.py", line 184, in inner
self._setup()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.5-py2.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.5-py2.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 135, in __init__
logging_config_func(self.LOGGING)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 803, in dictConfig
dictConfigClass(config).configure()
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 568, in configure
'filter %r: %s' % (name, e))
ValueError: Unable to configure filter 'require_debug_true': Cannot resolve 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue': No module named RequireDebugTrue
```

I figured that this error is because of the global_settings.py in the egg of `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.5-py2.7.egg/` which tries to configure a filter which does not exist in Django 1.6 anymore. Remember that my app runs with Django 1.6.

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.5-py2.7.egg/django/conf/global_settings.py contains:

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'filters': {
    'require_debug_false': {
        '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse',
    }
},
```

Now the simple solution is of course to remove that filter and voila. But what if there was a more delicate incompatibility? How do I correctly reuse an app the requires `Django>=1.3,<=1.4.5` in my Django 1.6 project? My humble understanding of virtualenv tells me that this is not the solution, right? Shouldn't editlive try to use Django 1.6 and maybe fail horribly but at least not install and try to use an older version of Django? If virtualenv is the solution, how does my app know that the other app should run in the older Django version?

Comment: Is there any reason why not just downgrade your own app to Django 1.4.5? Seems to me like the cleanest solution

Comment: Good idea! But suppose I wannted to reuse a third app which requires Django 1.5.5, how would I solve this?

Comment: You can't use two apps, one of which requires Django <= 1.4.5 and one of which requires >= 1.5.5. They're simply incompatible.

Comment: Overall I'd say Django 1.4 (and it's subsidiaries) is the most well supported version out there, there are hardly any libraries not supporting it at the moment (and 1.5 support is spreading constantly). Even in the rare occasion where you do find some library with support for < 1.4, someone out there probably already updated it to fit 1.4 (*ahem* github)

Comment: So the overall tone is: Use Django 1.4.x or fix the app myself. One question remains: Which version of Django is actually used by my app resp. the editlive? Will they use their associated version, both 1.6, or else?

Comment: Just realized it fails on `django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue` and not `django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse`. The `RequireDebugTrue` filter is in my settings.py, so I guess everything falls back to use Django 1.4.5?

Comment: yep. `"Use Django 1.4.x or fix the app myself"` you said it better than I did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, thanks for all the comments. You helped me to answer my questions and to improve my basic understanding. Not all of the comments to my questions are 100% correct. I have to stress that Django minor releases are all backwards compatibel unless otherwise stated in the release notes and except the deprecations. Please read [Django release process](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/internals/release-process/).

So basically all code written for Django 1.4.5 or 1.5.5 should still run under Django 1.6, and you should also be able to mix it. So it is possible to write a Django 1.6 app, reuse one 1.4.5 app and one 1.5.5 app as long as you run it in a Django version 1.6<=version<2.0.

The issue in my case was editlive defining its dependency to Django>=1.3,<=1.4.5 which caused the setup tool to download and install Django 1.4.5 onto my system. What I did not realize is that my own application started to use Django 1.4.5 from that point on. The error thrown afterwards was due to the usage of `django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue` in my own app. This filter was only introduced in Django 1.5 and thus would not run under 1.4.5.

I just had to delete the entire 1.4.5 egg directory and voila, everything works again.

I did not test the functionality of editlive yet, but at least there aren't any errors at 'compile time'.