# Django App installation throws error require_debug_false

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

I worked on an django-based website locally. I have Django 1.5.4 installed on my machine. Now I wanted to test the site on pythonanywhere. They only support Django 1.3 and Django 1.6, but I read that versions greater than 1.3 should work under 1.6 ([Reusing Django apps in own project wich require a lower django version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20239626/reusing-django-apps-in-own-project-wich-require-a-lower-django-version))

On calling syncdb I get an error:

```
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
   execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 429, in execute_from_command_line
   utility.execute()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 252, in fetch_command
app_name = get_commands()[subcommand]
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 101, in get_commands
apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 276, in __getattr__
self._setup()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 142, in __init__
logging_config_func(self.LOGGING)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 803, in dictConfig
dictConfigClass(config).configure()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 568, in configure 'filter %r: %s' % (name, e))

ValueError: Unable to configure filter 'require_debug_false': Cannot resolve 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse': No module named RequireDebugFalse
```

I read some issues about 'require_debug_false' but didn't find a solution. 
What do I have to change to use my Django-project under Django 1.6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check virtualenv:

http://www.tonido.com/blog/index.php/2013/11/25/working-with-virtualenv-on-django-projects/
http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/02/09/starting-a-django-project-the-right-way/

With the virtualenv you can work with differents versions of django in your machine

Comment: PythonAnywhere dev here -- that's a great recommendation.  We have instructions on how to set up a virtualenv on PythonAnywhere here: https://www.pythonanywhere.com/wiki/VirtualEnvForNewerDjango